# No such file or directory

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lamp

I'm building an EC2 LAMP server for the first time, and so far so good.

Except I can't seem to get the

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';` working right

I get this error message whenever I write that line above

```
Warning: require(/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/tables.php on line 6 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/tables.php on line 6
```

I know I have those files. My path to the file is:

`/home/ec2-user/vendor/composer/autoload.php`

The files that represent my web page are in

`/var/www/html/`

I can verify both using Filezilla.

Do I need to configure permissions, or move the whole vendor folder to a place where it can be accessed? Did I make an error with the path?

Thanks in advance.

---

`ps aux | grep apache` gives me this: I think this means that its running under ec2-user?

How do I switch it, then?

```
apache    1511  0.0  1.5 407000  9376 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1512  0.0  1.3 407376  8380 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1513  0.0  1.5 406996  9368 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1514  0.0  1.3 406880  8388 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1515  0.0  1.5 406880  9368 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1516  0.0  1.3 406880  8320 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1517  0.0  1.5 406880  9356 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1518  0.0  1.3 406880  8380 ?        S    15:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
ec2-user  2191  0.0  0.1 103416   828 pts/0    S+   17:45   0:00 grep apache
```

Comment: Have you tried `require 'vendor/composer/autoload.php';`?

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah, but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/home/ec2-user has only rwx------ permissions, thous webserver ( running as apache), doesn't have read rights.
Do a

```
chmod 755 /home/ec2-user
```

Comment: will this be okay for security?

Comment: Yes, that changes only /home/ec2-user and not the files in it. Or you can move the 'vendor' folder to somewhere else (/var/www/html/vendor, /srv/www/vendor), plenty choices, in some case may require additional apache config.

Comment: well, that worked, but now I have an unrelated error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess wrong owner of the files. Apache would be running as `apache`,`apache2`,`httpd` or `www-data` user (those are the usual ones). If you created those files as somebody else, the webserver probably cannot read them.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Do you suggest, then, that I login as apache, or something, then install composer?

Comment: If it is not a security risk, you could just add the read privilege for the apache user (or for all), but generally i don't recommend that. If you can, issue the `chown` command (either as a root or the owner of files) and change the ownership of files to the apache user.

Comment: I input `chown -R  apache home/ec2-user/vendor`, but it says `no such file or directory`, despite me confirming the path with filezilla.

Comment: you have written the relative path, you probably meant `chown -R apache /home/ec2-user/vendor`
also, have you confirmed the apache really runs under `apache` user?

Comment: I did the command successfully. No change. No, I have not confirmed that the apache really runs under apache user. How do I check that, or switch it?

Comment: Type `ps aux | grep apache` and it will show you what user it's running under. From what I remember, it's usually either www-data or apache2.

Comment: I'll update my question with what I get from that command. I think it's running under ec2

Comment: Could you run the `ls -l` command on the folder where your php files are? (feel free to change their names if it is an issue, i'm curious about the privileges.
The solution Sandor provided you is generally considered dangerous. You just allowed everybody to read and execute anything in those folders. If you happen to use htpasswd for some basic authentication (and you located it here), or if your source code contains e.g. db connection password, you just exposed it open for every user on the system. :)